# Do constexpr structs get zero-initialized?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following example:

```
template<int N>
struct foo {
    constexpr foo() : a() {}
    int a[N];
};

int main() {
    foo< (foo<1>{}).a[0] > f;
}
```

When trying to compile this, clang deduces `foo<0>` as the type of `f` while  `g++` crashes with an internal compiler error.

However, is the `a`-member of `foo<1>` guaranteed to be zero, or is this undefined/unspecified behaviour?

Comment: If g++/trunk still shows this behaviour, I'd file a(nother) bug report. Even though one could argue that it's compliant, the "error message" is not very helpful. Additionally, it is accepted if we remove the `constexpr` stuff: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1bfbb1dc146eeed

Comment: dyp: Yes, I actually filed a bug report at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63904 before posting the question. Maybe a link to your answer should be added since it contains potentially valuable information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The member-initializer `a()` value-initializes `foo::a` (via [class.base.init]/7, this leads to [dcl.init]/11). [dcl.init]/8 specifies that value-initialization for arrays value-initializes each element of the array. For `int`s (and other fundamental types), this leads to zero-initialization.

This has nothing to do with `constexpr`. An internal compiler error typically is a bug; it can also mean you exceeded some implementation-defined limits - which doesn't seem to be the case here.

As [Piotr S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3953764/piotr-s) notes in a comment, the expression `foo< (foo<1>{}).a[0] >`, if we assume `foo<1>{}).a[0] == 0`, leads to the declaration of a zero-sized array. Those are not legal in C++; so one could argue that g++'s behaviour is compliant.